# Acrylic tub set in mortar not level

Tags: bathroom

I hired someone to help me install an acrylic alcove bathtub that's base is to be set in mortar and thought I was getting a professional so I trusted that he checked level and didn't check it myself. Turns out the tub is level along it's length side to side but is down in the front by quite a few degrees and I didn't discover this until well after the mortar had set. I decided to go ahead anyway and install the direct to stud 3 wall surround and the tub not being level has thrown everything else off. Can I remove the tub without damaging it and start over?

Comment: how much out of level is it?

Comment: A photo doesnt hurt

Comment: Does water pool in it, or go out the drain?